# Backpack Crud Filter by relation

Tags: php, laravel-backpack

I have these 2 models: **Purchase** and (has many) **Payments**

in **Purchase Model** I have this relation and getter field

```
protected $appends = ['paymentstatus'];

public function payments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Payment::class, 'purchase_id');
}

public function getPaymentstatusAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->payments->count() > 0 ? '1' : '0';
}
```

In **Purchase List Controller**, I tried to add filter whether Payments exist or not but not working....

```
$this->crud->addFilter([
    'name'  => 'paymentstatus',
    'type'  => 'dropdown',
    'label' => 'Payment Status'
], [
    '0' => 'Unpaid',
    '1' => 'Paid'
], function($value) { // if the filter is active
    $this->crud->addClause('where', 'paymentstatus', $value);
});
```

I keep getting Search Error when selecting the filter.. What is the problem? Should't **paymentstatus** treated like a normal column for Purchase model?

Answer (score 0):

In your `Purchase` model you need to add:

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function payments()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Payment::class, 'purchase_id', 'id');
}
```

Then add a clause to check whether it has payment entries or not:

```
$this->crud->addClause('whereHas', 'payments');
```

If you need to filter further on fields within payments:

```
$this->crud->addClause('whereHas', 'payments', function(Builder $query) {
    $query->where('active', true);
    $query->whereNull('refuned_date');
});
```